# AbstractMethodError found when running unit test in Eclipse not when running in Cygwin

Tags: java, eclipse, cygwin, java-6

Here is the stacktrace:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

```
org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getXmlStandalone()Z
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:373)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:127)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:94)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:661)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:707)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    ...
```

I run into this problem when running the unit test in Eclipse, but everything works fine if I run it with Maven in Cygwin. I have searched in previous posts and understand that `"this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled."` My question is that what could the different results indicate? Wrong jar (package) used in Eclipse project setting? I am using jdk 1.6.0_27 in Cygwin, Eclipse project has the same settings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have `xercesImpl.jar` in the class path.

If you are using `xerces.jar`, remove it from the classpath and add `xercesimpl.jar` in the classpath.